# Scrape premium Yahoo Finance data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I try to scrape financial data from Yahoo finance; to be more precise, I need income, balance sheets, and cash flow statements ([https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/financials?p={ticker}](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%7Bticker%7D/financials?p=%7Bticker%7D)).
I use a combination of Beautiful Soup and Selenium webdriver since the tables are rendered dynamically with JS. Everything works fine. However, the free version of Yahoo Finance pulls financial data only for the last 4 years, whereas a premium subscription gives up to 40 years.
And it's where I got stuck on. The premium authorization works the following way:

1. While signing in user provides a username or email that has been used when signing up
2. System sends verification code to the email
3. User enters the code and gets access to the premium webpage with enhanced data.

So the question is - is there a way to sign in with Selenium webdriver? Or another method to trick nice Yahoo guys?

Thank you

Comment: You have to enter a new code from email every time you log in?

Comment: use yahoo finance API and make a auth request then it will return a token. And you can skip scraping website, just make calls to API to acquire data you want. https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/

Comment: Yahoo used to have a Finance API, but they don't any more.  Note that Yahoo has a legal incentive to make this hard.  The reason there is no longer a Finance API is because the brokers and stock exchanges got pissed off that Yahoo was giving away information that they charge Big Bucks for.  It's going to be an uphill climb.

Comment: @C. Peck Yes, every time it's new verification code

Comment: @CodeJonSnow Tim Roberts is right. There's no Finance API anymore. I tried a number of financial data providers and no one has the data comprehension that Yahoo has. Probably institutional companies have but it costs a fortune.